# ReactJS. - Why does this work in ReactJS and not the other way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Hi I am trying to understand why this particular code worked and my prior code didn't work.

I have provided both the snippets below:

WORKING CODE:

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
      let { value } = e.target;
      this.setState(state => { return ({searchField : value}) }, () => console.log("new state is ", this.state.searchField))
  }
```

NOT WORKING CODE:
The error i get here is `cannot read property value of null.`

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
      this.setState(state => { return ({searchField : e.target.value}) }, () => console.log("new state is ", this.state.searchField))
  }
```

THIS IS THE RENDER METHOD THAT IS COMMON TO BOTH:

```
  render() {
    let { monsters, searchField } = this.state;

    const filteredMonsters = monsters.filter((monster) => {
        return monster.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
    })

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Monster Name" onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
          <CardList monsters={filteredMonsters}/>
        </div>
    );
```

Can someone please explain why the destructuring syntax works?

Thank you!

Comment: You're passing a function that's going to access `e.target` at some point in the future while the working snippet extracts the value right when the event happens. Apparently the event is not guaranteed to provide a `.target` unless accessed immediately.

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain then why does this work this.setState({searchField : e.target.value}) even though this.setState is asynchronous this still works.

Comment: It's asynchronous but you're passing a value, the current value of `e.target.value`. In your non-working code, you're passing a *function*, and only when that actually runs does React try to access the value, but at that point the object pointed to by `e` has already been cleared. Basic demo: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qs316vkg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event is a Synthetic event that is passed to event handlers. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html):

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

```
function onClick(event) {
  console.log(event); // => nullified object.
  console.log(event.type); // => "click"
  const eventType = event.type; // => "click"

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(event.type); // => null
    console.log(eventType); // => "click"
  }, 0);

  // Won't work. this.state.clickEvent will only contain null values.
  this.setState({clickEvent: event});

  // You can still export event properties.
  this.setState({eventType: event.type});
}
```

> **Note**:
>
> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
>   should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, can you please explain then why does this work `this.setState({searchField : e.target.value})` even though this.setState is asynchronous this still works.

Comment: @pi2018 Mostly if callback is used inside `setState`, then the event doesn't persist

Answer (score 2):

Because one, `setState` is asynchronous, and two, React reuses the synthetic event objects. Therefore the value of `e` when the setState's callback is *executed* doesn't have to be (and apparently isn't) the same as when setState itself is *called*.

`const value = e.target.value; this.setState( // use the value primitive here` should work just as well.